# Adding observable to already existing axios post request

Tags: typescript, post, rxjs, axios, observable

I have an api which uses axios to send http post, the http post contains logs which are found in a file. The entirety of the logs is sent in one go when then user logs into the system.

I have been told to alter the code by adding rxjs, and send the contents of the file(logs) in streams of every x mins....

How would you go about solving this problem, any sort of resources or help will be of use?

```
async sendSomething(UserName: string, Log: string[]): Promise<UserInfo>{
  return this.apiService.post({
    baseUrl: Something.SomethingUrl
    endpoint: "/post/log"
    timeout: 15000
    headers:{      }
   },
    {
      userName: userName
      Log: Log[0]
     }
```

Comment: *streams of x bytes or every x mins*. One, the other or both? These 2 options are pretty different. I think you need to a bit more specific about the requirement.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, i've edited the question. Every x mins would be a better option.

Answer (score 0):

Look into using [axios-observable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-observable) instead of axios. This way you're working with subscriptions instead of promises which can be unsubscribed from (big win there).  I would then put your log sending request subscription inside of a BehaviorSubject (import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';) and setup the call to the behavior subject on a timer.  Something like this:

```
export default class PollValue<T> {
    date: Date;
    value: T;

    constructor(value: T) {
        this.date = new Date();
        this.value = value;
    }

    // Ensures a minimum amount of time has elapsed
    getTimeout(minTimeMS: number) {
        const timeElapse = new Date().getTime() - this.date.getTime();
        return timeElapse < minTimeMS ? minTimeMS - timeElapse : 0;
    }
}

// using true or false to indicate whether we sent logs the last time or not
const sendLogs = new BehaviorSubject(new PollValue<boolean>(false));
sendLogs.subscribe(lastValue => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        if (thereAreLogsToSend) {
            // sendLogs is a function containing your axios-observable instance and request 
            this.yourLogService.sendLogs(<pass logs here>).subscribe(result => {
                sendLogs.next(new PollValue(true));
            });
        } else {
            sendLogs.next(new PollValue(false));
        }
         
    }, lastValue.getTimeout(900000)); // ensure at least 15 mins have elapsed before sending again

    if (somestopsendingcondition) {
        sendLongs.unsubscribe();
    }
});
```

As for sending your request as a stream, I'd take a look at the examples [here](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/961). I haven't really work with streams using REST architecture much so I wouldn't be the best resource to help you there.
Hope this helps, though, I know the response was probably entirely too late...